# Как определить на каком мониторе находится окно, и как открыть его на другом?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, браузер, webapi

Открываю окно через `window.open(url, name, params)`, при закрытии запоминаю размеры и положение, при повторном открытии размещаю окно по сохраненным координатам и с сохраненными размерами. Все идет хорошо до тех пор пока не перетащу новое окно на второй монитор, в этом случае при повторном открытии окно открывается на первом мониторе с размерами и координатами как при закрытии на втором.
Как определить на каком мониторе находится окно, и как открыть его на другом?

Comment: Скорее всего никак, так ка к браузеры вроде бы не предоставляют никаких API, которые позволяли бы узнать подобное

Comment: Для чего это вам, можно пару слов.

Comment: Есть некоторый редактор кода, в отдельном окне открывается демка с результатами работы этого кода, обвешенная разными отладочными контролами. Для удобства пользования этого окна с демкой, записываются координаты и размеры, но вот на каком мониторе пользователь разместил окно определить не получается.

Comment: Понятнее не стало, но может этот пример поможет https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/presentation-api/